# How to Validate multidimensional array and use request value as parameter in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this `$request` multidimension array

```
$this->validate(
    $request, [
        'items' => 'required|array',
        'items.*.Quantity' => 'numeric|min:' . $request['items']['Packages']['min'] . '|max:' . $request['items']['Packages']['max'],
        'items.*.Link' => 'required|url',
    ]
);
```

Notice that Packages is also array, how do I access that value in validate. If I use it like that it gives   array to string conversion of course .I can do it with ForEach in other complicated method but I want to know if is there a simple way in Laravel ?

Comment: `$request['items']['Packages']['min']` the error is from here. `$request['items']` is an array not string.

Comment: Yes I know I said it gives array to string conversion.It was just an example.